# AngularJS ng-model converts object to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following in my HTML file:

```
    <td style="width: 200px;">
        <span ng-repeat="list in listGroups">
            <label for="{{ list.description }}" />{{ list.description }}</label>
            <input ng-model="$parent.listGroup" id="listGroup-{{ list.value }}"  name="listGroups" value="{{ list }}" type="radio" />
        </span>
   </td>
```

The listGroups contains:

```
[
    {
        "description": "New by Territory",
        "group": "product",
        "type": "new"
    },
    {
        "description": "New by Genre",
        "group": "genre",
        "type": "new"
    },
    {
        "description": "Charts by Territory",
        "group": "product",
        "type": "chart"
    },
    {
        "description": "Charts by Genre",
        "group": "genre",
        "type": "chart"
    }
]
```

When I click a radio button the listGroup (set in ng-model) becomes, for example:

```
{"description":"New by Genre","group":"genre","type":"new"}
```

When I look at listgroup with `typeof $scope.listGroup`, I see that it is a string now!

As such, I can't access it's properties in the other bindings in the rest of the HTML page.

In this case, I want `ng-show="listGroup.group == 'genre'"`

What's happening here and, more importantly, how do I make it do what I want it to do, which is keep the object as an object?

Thanks all

Dave

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the input's `value` attribute only accepts *strings*, not *objects* (check [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.radio)). When you do this: `value="{{ list }}"`, you are basically doing `input.value = list.toString()`.

One possible workaround is to use the `$index` of the `ng-repeat` directive. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/cKttd/

Comment: Also, don't use `$parent.`, it can bring you problems in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to use `ng-value`.

Example

`<input ng-model="$parent.listGroup" id="listGroup-{{ list.value }}"  name="listGroups" ng-value="{{ list }}" type="radio" />`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to have an object as an ng-model? That is what's causing your listGroup variable to become a string, since ng-model only works with strings. If you have a complex object that you want to use with ng-model, you should create a directive and implement a parser and a formatter, like this: [How to do two-way filtering in angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

You could also JSON.parse(object-in-string) , but I think I like @bmleite solution better. Just throwing this out there -- incase someone has a different use-case.