# AngularJS format array values in textarea

Tags: angularjs

I have a angularJS application, in which I have an array.

```
  $scope.data[0] =  x1;
  $scope.data[1] =  x2;
```

and a text area

```
  <textarea ng-model="data"> </textarea>
```

I can see the that textarea contains values x1, x2 (separated by comma). I want to show the values on separate lines. Meaning all array values should be separated by new line character not by comma. Do I need to write filter for this?

Comment: U can try filter and if it doesn't work, ask again :) Why didn't u try this solution?

Comment: I think it is doing toString on the array,to return x1,x2. You need to create a filter for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can write a directive that modifies how ng-model converts variables into input values and back.  I'm just writing this off the top of my head, so I have no idea if it's exactly right, but something like this might do it:

```
app.directive('splitArray', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            function fromUser(text) {
                return text.split("\n");
            }

            function toUser(array) {                        
                return array.join("\n");
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
        }
    };
});
```

And you can use it like this:

```
  <textarea ng-model="data" split-array> </textarea>
```

Comment: You can look to this answer for more examples of formatters and parsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js

Answer (score 16):

This is exactly what `ng-list` does:

```
<textarea ng-model="someArray" ng-list="/\n/"></textarea>
```

This also works on all other kinds of inputs as it hooks into ngModels parsers/formatters.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbYzT/1/

The problem with this is that ng-list always joins with a ',' as the separator, so it's not really bi-directional.

Comment: The only problem with this is that `ngList` always joins an existing array with `, ` as the separator, ignoring the user-selected separator - even if it is not a regex.

Comment: Ted: yes, that's an ugly issue - and it's not easy to fix as you cannot really revert splitting by regexp. Updated the comment to reflect that.

Comment: AngularJS 1.3 is removing support for regexes in ngSplit, making it a moot point.

Answer (score 16):

A much easier way to do this in **Angular >= 1.3** which works both ways:

```
<textarea ng-model="yourStringArray" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QgWKTRsC6TBeqbFf80fO?p=preview)

Comment: This really needs more upvotes. What a great answer.

Comment: very nice brow!

Comment: @AlisomMartins, thanks, your brow looks quite nice too.