# How do I show iterate data inside textarea in html using forEach in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is what i have on my controller:

```
$scope.order = [];
var values = CartService.cart;

angular.forEach(values, function (value, key) {
    $scope.order.push(value.cart_item_name);
});
```

This part is for the Textarea box:

```
$scope.payTrans = {
    myOrder: --->equals to something to get all the data
}
```

And this the html textarea box:

```
<textarea  style="height: 500px;"
           class="bookingtextareamargin"
           placeholder="Comments"
           ng-model="payTrans.myOrder">
    This where i want to show all the data like :
    Item 1
    item 2
    Item 3
    Item 4
</textarea>
```

Comment: same idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586159/angularjs-format-array-values-in-textarea

Comment: Could look into using something like [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) where you iterate over a collection in the HTML to display your list.

Comment: if i do that I get    [Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: I have no idea how to get the values inside [Object, Object, Object, Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `join` (js), and `\n` for newline

`$scope.payTrans.myOrder = $scope.order.join('\n');`

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <textarea id="textarea" ng-model="payTrans.myOrder">      
 </textarea>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.order = [];
    var values = [{
        cart_item_name: 'item1'
    },
    {
        cart_item_name: 'item2'
    },
    {
        cart_item_name: 'item3'
    },
    {
        cart_item_name: 'item4'
    }    
    ];

    angular.forEach(values, function (value, key) {
        $scope.order.push(value.cart_item_name);
    });

    console.log('s', $scope.order);

    $scope.payTrans = {
        myOrder: $scope.order.join('\n')
        };

}]);
```

Comment: Its not working i get error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'myOrder' of undefined`

Comment: Hey bro, Thank you So Much Now i will never this now. On this `$scope.payTrans = {
        myOrder: $scope.order.join('\n')
        };` I was missing  $scope.order.join('\n') This is how i was calling it just --- > order then got something like undefined

Comment: 2 days I was trying to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: Now I see this going to look very messy in the database is there away I could set each item to be on it's Row?

Comment: you welcome. if it's helpful for you should can mark this question as answered :).

about you last comment - I do not understand what you mean.. what you want to save to database? the text from textarea or from array?

Comment: yeah to save the array, each item to have it's own row  and id in the database, because now i'm just saving it as a single piece of text. it's not easy to find which item  that has been added. it's just messy. I don't know how to do that.