# Angular-Kendo Date Format Behavior

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Hello All,

I am running into some problems when using the Kendo-UI date picker in my angular application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance, 
 Drew

#### Issue

When using the angular-kendo directive for the date picker along with a date format a date object put into the model. The desired behavior is to store a string in the model as formatted by the options.

#### Javascript Versions

Angular-Kendo 0.5.2 2013-07-26

AngularJS v1.0.5

jQuery jQuery v1.9.1

#### Snippet from Template

```
<input type="text" name="publicationDate" ng-model="preview.publicationDate"  kendo-date-picker="dateOptions" k-options="dateOptions" />
```

#### Date Options

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    format: "yyyy-MM-dd"
};
```

#### Output

```
Date object stored in model: Tue Sep 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

```
Desired string to be stored in model: 2013-09-17
```

**Questions**

1. Is there any remedy for this issue?
2. Am I using the directive correctly?

Answer (score 4):

In Kendo UI 2014 Q2 (2014.2.625), this is fixed by using k-ng-model instead of ng-model.

Answer (score 3):

I think what is going on is that when you are binding through ng-model, kendo is returning the value of

```
.value()
```

In your controller, I believe you can do this:

```
$scope.$watch('preview.publicationDate'), function (val) {
    if (val) {
       $scope.preview.publicatonDate = kendo.toString(val, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This code helps to change the kendo-date-time-picker to the desired format

```
<input kendo-date-time-picker
             k-options="monthSelectorOptions"
             k-format="'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

### Possible Solution

I was able to do a work around by creating a custom directive.
The sample provided by another stack overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js) demonstrates how to create a custom directive.

I still have some additional testing to do but it seems to be working. I am not sure if this is the most efficent way to get around the problem though.

### Snippet from Template

```
<input type="text" parsedate="yyyy-MM-dd" name="publicationDate" ng-model="preview.publicationDate" kendo-date-picker="" k-options="dateOptions"/>
```

### Custom Directive

```
module.directive("parsedate", function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel", link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            function parsedate(text, format) {
                return kendo.toString(text, attr.parsedate);
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(parsedate);
        }
    };
});
```