# Change how data is represented in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm actually not sure how to ask this question, and I'm probably using incorrect terms, so bear with me.

Angular sets up a 2-way data binding so that it makes it easy to work with the data on both sides.  But what if I want to change how that data is represented?

Let me give a concrete example.

I want a form with a checkbox, which if bound directly to a model, would be stored as true or false by Angular.  However, in another part of the webpage I want that value to show up as 0 or 1, not true or false.

Now sure I could go and make them use two different variables, and use ng-change or something like that to update one based on the other, but that seems overkill and convoluted.

Is there some special meta function or something I can define that lets me essentially translate the data as it goes back and forth?

Comment: it sounds like you're looking for a formatter.  Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/angularjs-ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers) to see if it gives you what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ngTrueValue` and `ngFalseValue` directives. They define what should be treated as `true` and `false` on a checkbox: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo"
       ng-true-value="OK"
       ng-false-value="BOO-HOO">
```

The model will either have a value of `"OK"` or `"BOO-HOO"` instead of the default `true` and `false` in the above example.

Alternatively, if you want the original model to retain its default values and only draw the custom ones from another variable, you could also use the `ngChange` directive:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo"
       ng-change="bar=foo&&'OK'||'BOO-HOO'">
```

Now, whenever `foo` changes, `bar` will have the corresponding alternative value. Just remember to assign `bar` an initial value (it will start out with no value at all).

Comment: The OP said "I want that value to show up as 0 or 1", the model should still hold true or false , it's just a change of the rendered view.

Comment: Yes, I was just updating the answer to reflect that as you were adding your comment.

Comment: Thanks! This does what I needed it to in an elegant way.  Brian S's comment about formatters though is also what I was looking for in the larger scope, but the ng-true/false setup does what I need for this specific project.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller...

```
$scope.getvalue(data)
{
if(data===true)
return 1; // write what ever you want...
return 0;
}
```

in your html page..
bind the normal one as `{{$scope.data1}}`  and other as `{{getvalue($scope.data1)}}`

Answer (score 0):

#### You can do some nice things with `ngBind`:

Check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cRhLN2p5N4PmI65ps6Gp?p=preview

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ok"> OK?

<h2>true or false: {{ ok }}</h2>
<h2>0 or 1: {{ ok ? 1 : 0 }}</h2>
```

Comment: Um... ternary expressions don't work in angular expressions. You need to use `cond&&val1||val2` instead, else it will break the template :)

Comment: @mingos angularjs supports ternary expressions since version 1.1.5, check this feature https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b

Comment: Thank you sir for enlightening me :). I've no idea how I missed this one. We learn something new every day, don't we? Cheers.