# Angularjs - Checking duplicated email on blur in directive

Tags: angularjs, unique, blur, directive

I ran into a problem when I want to check whether the mail has been registered or not in the db, but only on the blur event ( I dont want it to check on every change ). So I wrote a directive that I can re-use in other places in my app. But the problem is the directive keeps checking even when I still not blur out, Here is my plnkr for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/eUPFxIc78Wkl4mCX6hrk?p=preview

And here is my directive code:

```
app.directive('checkEmail', function(userService){
return{
    restrict: "A",
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function( scope, ele, attrs, ctrl ){

        ele.bind('blur', function(){
            console.log("Run in blur!");

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function( email ){
                console.log("Email is ", email);

                // Checking to see if the email has been already registered
                if( ele.val() && userService.isDuplicateEmail(email) ){
                    ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', true );                        
                }else{
                    ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', false );
                }
            });

        })
    }
}
```

})

Sorry I'm new to angular and this simple task already drives me nuts. PLease take a look at my directive and tell me what I can do to fix this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see here for working sample http://plnkr.co/edit/lT9kO4nU0OeBG3g8lULG?p=preview

Please don't forget to add scope.$apply to update your UI

```
app.directive('checkEmail', function(userService) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {

      ele.bind('blur', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          console.log("Run in blur!");
          // Checking to see if the email has been already registered
          if (userService.isDuplicateEmail(scope.email)) {

            ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', false);


            return scope.email;;
          } else {

            ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', true);

            return scope.email;
          }
        });


      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the specific detail and it works like a charm. But can you explain why when you put the code inside the scope.$apply and it works ? before I posted this question, I had tried something similar to your solution, I put the setValidity code in the beginning and then scope.$apply(); in the end. I thought it will run the $digest cycle one more to update UI but at that time I was wrong. Can you clear me up with that ?

Comment: @DucHong more likely you can do that in both ways. I just do that to make code more clean.

Comment: actually in this situation I cannot call a scope.$apply in the end, I thought it has something to do with the scope related, here is the modified version from your code, [http://plnkr.co/edit/lgDiHvqtvhY1dROUWLDF?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/lgDiHvqtvhY1dROUWLDF?p=preview)

Comment: @DucHong your scope.$apply was after 'return' so was never called, that is  please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/8IjT5En1TN7w0lNpTUNa?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check the email when blurred, then you don't need to pass it inside the `ng-model`'s `$parser`s array. Simply change the validity when it is blurred.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wXNcasjF1qvWoYxyXi7T?p=preview)**

Something like this:

```
   ele.bind('blur', function(){
      ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', ctrl.$viewValue && userService.isDuplicateEmail(ctrl.$modelValue));
      scope.$digest();
   });
```

Alternatively, if you are checking the email asynchronously from a server then this may not work in to your advantage. The following example is a better answer:

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/B44pZARI81gRPhdzJRlK?p=preview)**

The service below, requests for a list of emails from the server and resolving the promises whether the email exists(true) or not(false).

```
app.service('userServiceAsync', function($http, $q) {

  this.isDuplicateEmailAsync = function(email) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(), i;

    $http.get('users.json')
      .success(function(users) {
        for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          if(users[i].email == email) {
            deferred.resolve(true);
            return;
          }
        }
        deferred.resolve(false);
      })

      .error(function() {
        deferred.resolve(false);
      });

    return deferred.promise;
  };

});
```

The directive below, sets the `isDuplicatedEmail` validity key to true or false, depending on the resolved value of the `userServiceAsync.isDuplicateEmailAsync ()` method. As a bonus, I added a determinant key within the `ngModelController`'s object to check if the asynchronous request is still on going or not (using the `__CHECKING_EMAIL` key).

```
app.directive('checkEmailAsync', function(userServiceAsync) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('blur', function() {
        ctrl.__CHECKING_EMAIL = true;
        userServiceAsync.isDuplicateEmailAsync(ctrl.$viewValue).then(function(hasEmail) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', !hasEmail);
        })['finally'](function() {
          ctrl.__CHECKING_EMAIL = false;
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  Check Email Asynchronously
  <input type="text" name="emailAsync" placeholder="Email" ng-model="emailAsync" check-email-async required />
  <div ng-show="registerForm.emailAsync.__CHECKING_EMAIL">
    Checking Email...
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the support, actually I will need an asyn call in my real app as you said. But I have some other things to ask from your answers
1) When should I use `$parsers`, I've read some tutorials about custom validation and all they used is this `$parsers` or `$formatters` thing, 
2) Checking out your async example, as the error output still doesn't show, I've changed the out to something like `<span style="color:red" ng-show="registerForm.emailAsync.$error.isDuplicateEmail">Email already used</span>` and using scope.$apply() for the UI update, but nothing changes. Any ideas why ?

Comment: `$parsers` are used to format text from the view(the input value) to the model(the $scope value). As for the async problem, I have fixed it, use `isDuplicatedEmail`, check the second DEMO again.

Comment: thanks, but can you check again the second demo link ? Seem like it's still the old version and the error output still doesn't show when the email is duplicated. Thanks. 
I changed a little bit like this and it works, `ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', **!hasEmail**);`

Comment: I've edited it, its the same as what you mentioned in your comment now.

Answer (score 1):

$parser.unshift is executed when the model changes, but you really wanted "blur",... either check ngModelOptions' "updateOn" or remove unshift...

you can also use ctrl.$viewValue.

```
        ele.bind('blur', function(){
            console.log("Run in blur!");

            //ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function( email ){
                email = ctrl.$viewValue;
                console.log("Email is ", email);

                // Checking to see if the email has been already registered
                if( !!email && userService.isDuplicateEmail(email) ){
                    ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', true );

                    return email;;
                }else{
                    ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', false );

                    return email;
                }

            //});

        })
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, that `ngModelOptions` is really new to me. but can you explain more clearly about the way we use `$parser` or `$formatter` thing? I've read some tutorials about custom validation on directives and most of them use these in their custom functions. I thought I was on the right path but it was not

Comment: this might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/angularjs-ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers

Answer (score 1):

@ryeballar , sorry but this still doesn't look right to me. I've modified your plnk so that it just works on the async. So the confusion I have is this line
`ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', !hasEmail);`, you can visit new plnk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWnbem6BnbVw3iGXmvJb?p=preview)

That boolean value doesn't seems to be right if I dont put a "**!**" before, you can check it in the console log and see its value, like when an email is not duplicated, the service return false, then we set the validity to `"TRUE"` in order to make it look `"RIGHT"`.

Here is the directive:

```
elem.bind('blur', function() {
    ctrl.__CHECKING_EMAIL = true;
    userServiceAsync.isDuplicateEmailAsync(ctrl.$viewValue).then(function(hasEmail) {
        console.log("hasEmail: ", hasEmail);
        console.log("!hasEmail: ", !hasEmail);

        scope.hasEmail = hasEmail;
        // HERE IS THE CONFUSION, WHY !hasEmail works correctly ????
        // THIS WILL GIVE THE WRONG ANSWER
        // ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', hasEmail);

        // THIS WILL GIVE THE RIGHT ANSWER
        ctrl.$setValidity('isDuplicatedEmail', !hasEmail);


    })['finally'](function() {
      ctrl.__CHECKING_EMAIL = false;
    });
  });
```