# angular: nested directive ngmodel

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel

Asume we have a directive with a nested directive inside. Both directives want to alter the data before it's being displayed. I used ngModelController to do that but I'm open for other suggestions.

My problem: I can't get it to work without using scope.$apply() but on the other hand scope.$apply() throws an error when I use it what would indicate that it's unnecessary.

Here is a plunkr to the problem: http://embed.plnkr.co/RROBxuITLpYnGkHSQAe3/preview

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code is supposed to be **in the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read more about `ngModelController`, especially about `$formatters` `$parsers` and `$render`. This is great tutorial: http://www.chroder.com/2014/02/01/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/. They are also explaind in that question: [ngModel Formatters and Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers)

In your case you can replace `$watch` with formatter function. Formatters are called when value is changed from controller. You can manipulate the data in formatter function and then it will be set as `$viewValue`. Good practice is to use as few $watches as possiblle.

Also, imho using:

```
scope: {
 myVal: '=ngModel'
}
```

Looks bad. It might be confusing for other programmers who will work with your code. `ngModel` should be used by placing it in `require` property.

I would do it in that way:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ve1Ipm53BiYorjtxron5?p=preview