# How to get the meridian (am / pm) with momentsjs and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date, momentjs

I have a question about the library moments.js, I have an application in angularjs where I have six select elements for the year, month, day, hour, minutes, and am / pm format. I am using the following format moment to build m.format date ('YYYY-MM-DD hh: mm: ss a).

The code is as follows:

```
var m = moment([scope.val.year, scope.val.month, scope.val.date, scope.val.hour, scope.val.minute]); //build date 

model.$setViewValue(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a'))
```

I get the data `m.hour ()`, `m.minute ()`, etc but there is a way to get the am / pm format, I have not found anything about it, something perhaps as `m.meridian () => "am "or" pm "`.

I would build the array passing as parameter if am or pm, and then also would get from any date if am or pm date.

Comment: look in the moment format docs...it's there

Comment: @charlietfl - actually, no it's not.

Comment: @MattJohnson sure it is `A` or `a` ... http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: @charlietfl - yes, but locale affects that.  `moment().format("a") == "pm"` will fail if (for example) `moment.locale() == 'zh-cn'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things:

- The word you're looking for is ["meridiem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock), not ["meridian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(geography)).  It's a Latin word meaning "mid-day".  A.M. is "ante meridiem" (before mid-day) and P.M. is "post meridiem" (after mid-day).
- The `.hours()` function and the input array passed to the `moment` constructor both expect hours of a 24-hour clock, from 0 to 23.  There is no built-in function to accept or output a 12-hour clock value, or a meridiem (am/pm).
- The parsing and formatting functions in moment do have options for 12-hour clock hours (`h` or `hh`) and meridiem (`A` or `a`), but you're not parsing or formatting in your use case, so they would be a bit clumsy to use.  In particular, they are based on moment's current locale settings, so testing a string would be problematic if the locale wasn't fixed to a specific language.
- You can use these simple functions to convert from 12-hour + meridiem to 24-hour and vice-versa.  They are not specific to moment, so you can also use them with the `Date` object or elsewhere.

  ```
  function hours12to24(h, pm) {
      return h == 12 ? pm ? 12 : 0 : pm ? h + 12 : h;
  }

  function hours24to12(h) {
      return {
          hour : (h + 11) % 12 + 1,
          pm : h >= 12
      }
  }
  ```

  To test these functions:

  ```
  function test() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
      var x = hours24to12(i);
      var h = hours12to24(x.hour, x.pm);
      console.log(i + " == " + x.hour + (x.pm ? " pm" : " am") + " == " + h);
    }
  }
  ```
- Also, be careful when calling `.month()` to get the month number, the results are 0-11, not 1-12. The same is true when building the input array.  Your dropdown either needs to use 0-11, or you need to add or subtract 1 accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it was very useful to me your solution.

Answer (score 13):

You could also do something like `m.format('a')`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is very good. It helped me to create my demo because with-out it I would have missed the point with the month (0 to 11).

But you don't need to create the meridiem function because it's already implemented in `moment.js`. The point is that the usage is not very clear from the docs.

You can use the `meridiem` function like this:

```
var curDate = moment().hour(yourHour); // create a moment date with the hour you'd like to test
var meridiem = curDate
            .localeData().meridiem(hour); // will return AM/PM String
```

If you need a boolean instead of `AM/PM` string you can pass the AM/PM string to `curDate.localeData().isPM(meridiem)`. That will return true or false.

The point with the month that you don't want to display 0 to 11 in your select can be fixed by a `displayLabel` function that will increment every value of the month array. Then you'll have it displayed 1 to 12 but stored as 0 to 11. If you're writing a directive that could be better handled by a [`$parser / $formatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers) function of `ngModel`.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/oh8ab845/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .filter('momentDate', MomentDateFilter)
 .filter('momentUTC', MomentUTCFilter)
 .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MomentDateFilter() {
 return function(input, format) {
        return moment(input).format(format);
    };
}

function MomentUTCFilter() {
 return function(input, format) {
        return moment.utc(input).format(format);
    };
}

function MainController($scope, $log) {
    var vm = this,
        now = moment();
    
    vm.checkHour = checkHour;
    vm.dateSelect = dateSelection();
    vm.displayLabel = displayLabel;
    vm.now = now;
    vm.selected = {
        "day": 27,
        "month": 8,
        "year": 2015,
        "hour": 18,
        "meridiem": "PM",
        "minutes": 6,
        "seconds": 20
    };
    
    function dateSelection() {
        return { // generated on every page load for demo
            // better store the generate object as json and load it
            day: createRange(1,31),
            month: createRange(0,11),
            year: createRange(1900, 2100),
            hour: createRange(0,24),
            minutes: createRange(0,59),
            seconds: createRange(0,59),
            meridiem: 'AM_PM'.split('_')
        };
 }
    
    function displayLabel(key, value) {
     if (key === 'month') {
         value++; // increment month for correct month value 1 to 12
        }
        return value;
    }
    
    function checkHour(key, hour) { // updates meridiem (AM/PM)
        if (key === 'hour') {
            var curDate = moment().hour(hour);
            //console.log('check hour', hour, curDate.hour(), curDate.localeData());
            vm.selected.meridiem = curDate
                .localeData().meridiem(hour);
            //console.log(curDate
            //    .localeData().isPM(vm.selected.meridiem));
        }
        //console.log('changed', key);
    }
    //console.log(this.dateSelect);
    function createRange(from, to) {
        var arr = [];
     for(i=from; i<=to; i++) {
         arr.push(i);
        }
        //console.log(arr);
        return arr;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl" class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, array) in mainCtrl.dateSelect" class="form-group">
            <label>{{key}}</label><select class="form-control" ng-change="mainCtrl.checkHour(key, array[mainCtrl.selected[key]])" ng-model="mainCtrl.selected[key]" ng-options="value as mainCtrl.displayLabel(key, value) for value in mainCtrl.dateSelect[key]" ng-disabled="key === 'meridiem'">
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    selected: <pre>{{mainCtrl.selected|json}}</pre>
    raw date (unformatted, UTC): {{mainCtrl.selected | momentUTC}}<br/>
    date formatted (meridiem locale): {{mainCtrl.selected | momentUTC : 'LLLL' }}<br/> 
    
    
    now (momentjs) {{mainCtrl.now}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the solution of Matt and your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the moment with the following function and use it in the same style as you set & get hour, day, minute etc..

```js
moment.fn.meridiem = function(newMeridiem) {
  if (!newMeridiem) {
    return this.format('A'); // or `return this.hours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';`
  }
  if (newMeridiem.toUpperCase() === 'AM' && this.hours() > 12) {
    this.hours(this.hours() - 12);
  } else if (newMeridiem.toUpperCase() === 'PM' && this.hours() <= 12) {
    this.hours(this.hours() + 12);
  }
  return this;
}

console.log("Current:",moment().meridiem());

console.log("Set as am result:",moment().meridiem('am').meridiem());

console.log("Set as pm result:",moment().meridiem('pm').meridiem());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Copied from https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3873