# moment get time period AM//PM localized

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Do we have a function like `moment.weekdays()` or `moment.months()` which will return AM PM localized? Something like `moment.period()`?

```
timeFormatDefaultLocale({
    "dateTime": "%A, der %e. %B %Y, %X",
    "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
    "time": "%H:%M:%S",
    "periods": ["AM", "PM"], <------ I need to pass moment function to get period
    "days":  moment.weekdays() as any,
    "shortDays": moment.weekdaysShort() as any,
    "months": moment.months() as any,
    "shortMonths": moment.monthsShort() as any
});
```

Comment: This will help-https://momentjs.com/

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802780/how-to-get-the-meridian-am-pm-with-momentsjs-and-angularjs

Comment: @Ankita Jaiswal can you please explain what exactly you required?

Comment: At this point of the code, I don't have the date, I will pass this format to localize the date.

Comment: @Ajinkya i want something like this: periods : moment.period(). moment.period() this is not a function in moment. I want a function which returns localized AM/PM like for days we have moment.weekDays()

Comment: @Ankita Jaiswal Thanks ... Please check with answer bellow

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this

```
 moment.format('A')
```

here `A` is for AM PM format

Please refer example bellow :

```js
  console.log('Current Time is :'+moment().format('hh:mm A')) ;
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want method which will return ["AM","PM"]. This will only return AM or PM.

Comment: @Ankita Jaiswal Sorry i am not getting you ? can you please elaborate ?

Comment: let AM = moment("05:30:00","HH:mm:ss").format('hh:mm A').split(' ')[1];
let PM = moment("15:30:00","HH:mm:ss").format('hh:mm A').split(' ')[1];                 "periods": [AM, PM], Have done like this  as workaround

Comment: that's working, but that's a workaround. There should be some standard method which should return this. I am looking for that method.

Comment: @Ankita Jaiswal Im also looking for it.. Please let me know if got something I will update it in answer

Comment: @Ajinkya I've posted an alternative answer, maybe you can be intersted to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in momentjs function to get `['AM', 'PM']` localized, if you look at [Accessing locale specific functionality](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) section of the docs, you will see that moment has `isPM` and `meridiem`:

```
localeData = moment.localeData()
// ...
localeData.isPM(amPmString);  // returns true iff amPmString represents PM
localeData.meridiem(hours, minutes, isLower);  // returns am/pm string for particular time-of-day in upper/lower case
// ...
```

Have a look at [Customize#AM/PM](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/) and [Customize#AM/PM Parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm-parsing/) sections to have further info on how moment manages meridiem.

For most of the locales you can write your own *workaround* function like this one (using [`moment(Object)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/), [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and [`locale()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/)):

```js
function period(locale) {
  return [
    moment({h: 0}).locale(locale).format('A'),
    moment({h: 23}).locale(locale).format('A')
  ];
}

['en', 'en-us', 'de', 'it', 'fr', 'zh-cn'].forEach(localeName => {
  console.log( localeName, period(localeName) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

If you nee to manage also locales that have multiple AM/PM values (e.g. `zh-cn`), you can use something like the following:

```js
function period(locale) {
  const result = new Set();
  let m = moment({h: 0}).locale(locale);
  for(let i=0; i<24; i++) {
    result.add( m.format('A') );
    m.add(1, 'h');
  }
  return Array.from(result);
}

['en', 'en-us', 'de', 'it', 'fr', 'zh-cn'].forEach(localeName => {
  console.log( localeName, period(localeName) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you consider using other libraries, note that [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) (momentjs *"younger brother"*) has the [`Info.meridiems()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/info.js~Info.html#static-method-meridiems) method that may help you, even if seem to handle always 2 values for AM/PM (See `zh-cn` result):

```js
const Info = luxon.Info;

['en', 'en-us', 'de', 'it', 'fr', 'zh-cn'].forEach(localeName => {
  console.log( localeName, Info.meridiems({ locale: localeName }) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.16.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```