# Showing a different view value from model value for dates in Angular

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-ui

I'm trying to implement a feature for a form where:
1. I display a date string in the format ***mm-dd-yyyy***
2. User is allowed to edit the form, and the date string would remain in the format ***mm-dd-yyyy***
3. When the user submits the form, the date string must be in the format ***yyyy-mm-dd***.
3. The original format of the date string is ***yyyy-mm-dd***.

I would prefer to achieve this somehow by means of a directive rather than calling a function everytime a user submits a form, was wondering if there were any thoughts on a good way to do this?

I've given angular-ui-mask a look but am not sure if this would help me so much for this case.

Thanks!

Comment: you can also do it in the submit method

Comment: Limitation here is that I'm using this form in many views, and would prefer to not do re-formatting on the submit method in each view

Comment: you would be reformatting 'incorrect' data before processing. you can in the submit method check if your date is in incorrect format and fix it before processing (e.g. trying to store the value)

Comment: Use formatters and parsers?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers