# How to use $scope.$watch and ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have working code:

```js
$scope.$watch('vm.reg', function (newValue) {
  if (newValue !=  null) {
    vm.reg = newValue.replace(/\D+/, '');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dest_regex" ng-model="vm.reg"/>
```

But I need to use `$watch` for `ng-repeat` something like this:

```html
<div ng-repeat="fi in filterElments">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dest_regex" ng-model="fi.reg"/>

    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dest_regex" ng-model="fi.reg"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dest_regex" ng-model="fi.reg"/>
     .................. -->
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working.. please explain with some detail.

Comment: Why you have use replace(/\D+/, '');, for replacing?

Comment: you do not need $watch, use ng-change, this attribute work like $watch for your input

Comment: @AmitRamoliya, i need to check each input separatly. Problem is one model fi.reg in ng-repeat, coz of that i cannot check each input separatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ng-Change as $watch for your ng-models in ng-repeat
>
> you can detect if input value has changes

```js
$scope.replacing = function(item){
  //do somthing
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="fi in filterElments">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dest_regex" ng-model="fi.reg" ng-change="replacing(fi)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you, ng-change really helped

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case I would suggest to look at ngModelController $parsers and $formatters.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22843592/274500