# AngularJS a directive for input type = number that watches for changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-directive

**the context**: I am developing a mobile version of my app. I want a user to be able to enter numeric fields with their [numeric keybord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QTO0.png) of their phone/tablet. AngularJS makes input fields with `type = "number"` unreachable for any non-integer data (which is any, because input is a string).


**the idea**: I want to make a directive that will somehow (using `$watch` or `$parsers` or any other ancient sorcery) convert input string to number.


**the issue**: My directive does not trigger changes of `$watch` when I type anything in the input field. *But when I change scope field from my cotroller $watch is triggered as planed.*

controller:

```
        // code minimized and omitted for clarity
        .controller('carController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.car = {
                power : null,
                // other fields
            }
        }]);
```

directive

```
angular.module('numeric', []).directive('numeric', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',

        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            // parsers does not affect anything
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                return parseInt(value);
            });

            // watcher does not watch
            scope.$watch('model', function(newVal, old) {
                if (typeof newVal == 'string') {
                    scope.car.power = parseInt(newVal);
                }
            }, true);

        }
    };
});
```

html

```
    <div ng-controller="carController">
     <input   
            ng-model="car.power"                      
            numeric
            name="power"
            type="number"
            pattern="[0-9]">
       </div>
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates such behavior http://jsfiddle.net/xo94sw7m/1/

**the question**: what am I missing and how to make directive work as planned?

What I have tried: using $formatters-$parsers,using different approaches to $watch (using `scope:false`, isolated scope, trying to watch scope changes using `attrs` and etc), nothing seems to work so far

Comment: I don't see the problem, `<input type="number">` fully supports floats

Comment: If you read the question or visit fiddle link you probably will see the problem.

Comment: I read the question and visited the fiddle, but why are you storing float as string? Just store it as float.

Comment: I am not storing float as string :) the only float in my question is `parseFloat()` and that is just bad copy-paste, I replaced in with `parseInt()`. But it does not make any difference - `type=number` will block .... wait.  It seems that u were right, i have just deleted my directive and input is accepted http://jsfiddle.net/aqkobhux/   I don't understand what originally was wrong then...

Comment: @RonDadon it appears that problem was in `pattern="[0-9]"` attribute... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
myApp.directive('number', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
                return parseInt(data);
            });
            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    var model = $parse(attrs['ngModel']);
                    model.assign(scope, parseInt(data));
                }
                return parseInt(data);

            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftn1n5q4/)

Comment: Could you, please, provide some explanation for $formatters part ?

Comment: Formatters are invoked when the model is modified in the code.You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/22843592/5621827 for more info.Also please marked this as accepted ans if it works for you.