# angular get absolute values from input fields

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to pass absolute values for input fields on form submit?

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="vm.saveInfo($event)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.hotel.numberOfGuests">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.hotel.emptyRooms">
</form>
```

or I need to manipulate those within controller, something as below

```
vm.hotel.numberOfGuests = Math.abs(vm.hotel.numberOfGuests)
vm.hotel.emptyRooms = Math.abs(vm.hotel.emptyRooms)
```

Comment: what do you mean with absolute values?

Comment: @almartinez they mean `1` instead of say `1.001` bit confusing because the inputs are of type `text` and not `number`

Comment: @George that's why I'm asking, if the input type is text you can't do that, you need to pass them as a numbers

Comment: @almartinez well somewhat, you can still use `Math.abs()` with a string

Comment: @almartinez, I need to pass absolute number so instead of -1 or '-1' get 1

Comment: @user1751287 but then you must use `input type="number"`

Comment: @George never seen that before, I hope the answer explain why that works

Comment: @user1751287 I just found on the doc that if you pass an string on `math.abs` it will say `NaN`

Comment: No matter whatever you are trying to do to the input value, you should use the $parsers pipeline to intercept and manipulate input values before they are applied to the model. See ths answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers