# How do I limit decimal places to only two numbers when paste number into input box using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have input box accepting decimal numbers with having decimal points limit upto 2 places. Also I am not allowing input to enter more than two decimal places.

eg. 9999.99

But now the problem is when I am copy some number i.e. 999999.9999 and paste it into input box I want result i.e. 999999.99

Meaning I want to truncate rest of the decimal places and don't want rounding as well.

How can I achieve this using angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngPattern directive.

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9][0-9])?$/">
```

This regex would enforce exactly two places (no more or less). Just change the regex to get whichever desired behavior you want.

Comment: my concern is numbers are not gets formatted when I am pasting it into input box

Comment: ngPattern will just give you a truthy value of whether the text currently in the box fits the regex. You can handle that however you like. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using `ng-model` along with `$formatters` and `$parsers`.

See more explanation here:

[ngModel Formatters and Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers)

This is a TypeScript adaptation from some code I use to force currency formats.

```
app.directive('myModelFormat', ['$filter', function myModelFormatDirective($filter:ng.IFilterService):ng.IDirective {

    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: myModelFormatLink
    };

    function myModelFormatLink(scope:ng.IScope, elem:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs:ng.IAttributes, ctrl:ng.INgModelController) {

        if (!ctrl) {
            return;
        }

        const decimalWithOneDigit:RegExp = new RegExp('\\' + STRINGS.decimalSym + '\\d$');

        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function myModelFormatFormatter(ignore:any):string {
            return $filter(attrs['myModelFormat'])(ctrl.$modelValue)
        });

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function myModelFormatParser(viewValue:string):any {
            const plainNumber:number = parseFloat(viewValue);
            let formatted:string = $filter(attrs['myModelFormat'])(plainNumber);

            // special case where they typed the decimal symbol but not a decimal value,
            // make sure we don't remove the symbol which prevents them from typing a decimal
            if (_s.endsWith(viewValue, STRINGS.decimalSym)) {
                formatted += STRINGS.decimalSym;
            }

            // alternate special case, they typed one decimal number, don't force it to zero, at least not yet..
            if (decimalWithOneDigit.test(viewValue)) {
                formatted = formatted.substr(0, formatted.length - 1);
            }

            elem.val(formatted);
            return plainNumber;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Is this code will work If I copy some numbers i.e. 9999.999 and paste it into input box and Is it will convert it to 9999.99 ?

Comment: @NilayMistry, yes, the format is applied properly to pasted values.