# AngularJS: add filter to type="number" input element before angular parse anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My web application is for persian users and they may enter numbers in persian digits.

I want to add a directive to my `<input>` elements with `type="number"` which converts persian digits to english digits. I should do this because I want to calculate sum of values of models binded to inputs. this is minified html code:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.count1">
<input type="number" ng-model="item.count2">
total count: {{item.count1 + item.count2}}
```

after reading best answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js) I write this directive:

```
module.directive('input', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
        if (attr.type !== 'number') return;

        function toEnglishNumber(value) {
            if (!value) {
                return;
            }
            var englishNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"],
                persianNumbers = ["۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"];

            for (var i = 0, numbersLen = persianNumbers.length; i < numbersLen; i++) {
                value = value.replace(new RegExp(persianNumbers[i], "g"), englishNumbers[i]);
            }
            console.log(value);
            return value;
        }

        function fromUser(text) {
            return toEnglishNumber(text);
        }
        ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
};
});
```

When I enter persian digits in input element, `toEnglishNumber` function is not called (`console.log(value)` is not invoked). but when I enter english digits this function id called. I think angular is ignoring value because it is not a number.

how can I tell angular let me parse the value before ignoring it? or is there a better solution? thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a filter for this?  You can invoke a filter from the controller.  I think it would be much cleaner and easier to implement [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller)

Comment: can I add a filter to ng-model? as I know the filters are added to databinding expressions. for example {{test|toEnglishDigit}}

Comment: hi please see here http://jsbin.com/levixi/1/edit?console,output looks like everything is fine

Comment: This part of your code is working fine, something else breaks

Comment: @sylwester: when numbers are in persians the result is not equal to sum of the input.

Comment: @Ali that's wired I've got 2 Persians numbers and result is 14. not just I've paste your code only

Comment: @Ali Are you on a machine with the persian locale?

Comment: @sylwester the sum of "۱۰" and "۱۰" should be "۲۰". but in my browser it is noting.

Comment: @runTarm Yes. I'm in ubuntu, using chrome browser, and change locale between persian and english when inserting characters.

Comment: @Ali please see here http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=25tzwwz&s=8#.U-TVQmPCc0E

Comment: It might have nothing to do with angularjs, but a "browser-locale" as in the ExpertSystem's answer. Try checking `inputElement.value` directly if it is an empty string when contains persian character.

Comment: @slywester thanks for your help. ExpertSystem is right and the problem is my browser locale, not angular.

Comment: @Ali Try the following format `var resp = $filter('getState')('1', states);` for using a filter.  I don't believe this will update the ng-model in this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is "browser-locale" specific. If a browser does not recognize a symbol (e.g. `۱۰`) as a numeric digit, then entering it in a number field makes the browser ignore (i.e. the fields value is empty (although there is content in the input field).

I am not sure if a browser with a Persian locale would correctly recognize the symbol as a numeric digit, but (in order to be on the safe side) I recommend you use an `input[type="text"]`.

Comment: how can I change my browser locale?

Comment: @Ali: The real question is how will you make sure that the user's browser-locale is right ? It is very risky to rely on that. (Besides, as I said, I am not sure changing the locale will change the number field's behavior.) Anyway, to change your browser's locale, you can follow the instructions **[here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#locales-testing)**.

Comment: I changed the locale but it's not fixed. with firefox there is no problem. the problem is something with chrome browser.

Comment: @Ali: That's why I said it is browser-specific (and you should use `type="text"` unless you like to leave dangerously :)).

Comment: @Ali Are your find any solution that use `type=number` instead of `type=text`?