# Creating directive that manipulates the ngmodel value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that does the following:

1. Has a default value when the input is empty.
2. Limits the input to a upper and lower bounds, when it exeeds these it is specifically set to the upper or lower it exceeded.

Here is my code using the link function:

```
app.directive('rangedInput', function ($parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            lower: "@",
            upper: "@",
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        link:
            function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                    return;
                }

                element.bind('blur', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var value = parseInt(element.val());
                    var upper = parseInt($scope.upper);
                    var lower = parseInt($scope.lower);

                    if (value > upper) {
                        value = upper;
                    } else if (value < lower) {
                        value = lower;
                    }

                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(value);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();  
                    });

                });
            }
    };
});
```

And the usage:

```
<label>{{model.Amount}}</label>

<input type="text" upper="1500000" lower="50000" ranged-input ng-model="model.Amount" />
```

I also tried one using the compile function:

```
app.directive('rangedInput', function ($parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            lower: "@",
            upper: "@", 
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        compile: function () {
            var getter, setter;
            return function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
                setter = getter.assign;

                if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                    return;
                }

                element.bind('blur', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var value = parseInt(element.val());
                    var upper = parseInt($scope.upper);
                    var lower = parseInt($scope.lower);

                    if (value > upper) {
                        value = upper;
                    }
                    else
                        if (value < lower) {
                            value = lower;
                        }

                    element[0].value = value;
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        setter($scope, value);
                    });

                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Neither work as desired, the problem that I am finding is that the value of `ng-model="model.Amount"` doesn't seem to get updated correctly?

Comment: You don't want to be binding to `blur` you want to make a `$parser` and/or a `$formatter`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js

Comment: @ivarni i only want it to happen when the users loses focus on the field, so that it doesn't change the value while they are typing...

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions with `updateOn: 'blur'` would work in conjunction with a `$parser`. I haven't tried it before though. I'd consider binding to a DOM event a last resort, but if that's what it takes go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code. Check this out.

```
app.directive('rangedInput', function ($parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            lower: "@",
            upper: "@",
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        link:
            function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                if (!ngModel) {
                    return;
                }

                element.bind('blur', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var value = parseInt(element.val());
                    var upper = parseInt($scope.upper);
                    var lower = parseInt($scope.lower);

                    if (value > upper) {
                        value = upper;
                    } else if (value < lower) {
                        value = lower;
                    }

                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                        ngModel.$render();  
                    });

                });
            }
    };
});
```