# AngularJS trims leading zeros in model, while view/input value still remains unchanged?

Tags: angularjs

For an input element with type number, when the number entered has leading zeros like '0000123456', the model is updated to 123456, while the view/input still remains the same 0000123456.

However if I switch from number to text everything works as expected. I would like to have number since it would display numeric keyboard for mobile devices.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="vm.orderid"/>
{{vm.orderid}}
```

**[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/m2UUfuXtq7oMNgQYOuvk?p=preview)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do two-way filtering in angular.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js)

Comment: Thanks for the info. What would I like to have is if the model is updated why the input fields is not updated and still has the wrong value ?

Comment: use input type ="tel"..

Comment: The binding model in angular by default only pushes things through when a change occurs, so the parser fires only when the UI changes and the formatter fires only when the model changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by @Steve, I used a custom directive `my-decimals` which matches the view value with the model when input losses the focus.

```
<input type="number" my-decimals ng-model="vm.orderid"/>

angular.directive('myDecimals', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

            elm.blur(function() {
                var val = ctrl.$viewValue;
                ctrl.$setViewValue(val * 1);
                ctrl.$render();
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a missing closing curly bracket? Can't get this directive to work! [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303191/leading-zeros-missing-within-number-input)

Comment: Your welcome, but I haven't been able to get it working. Just won't trigger.. :/

Answer (score 3):

You have to options for this, 
 **use:** `<input type = "tel">`
it has been introduced for this exact purpose. It's one of the new input types in HTML5.

**or**, `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]">`
It Will bring up the numeric keypad on iPhone and the  Android phones.You can test this. I am not 100%sure.

Comment: I'm using this way, I mean tel, but it still trim the leading zero