# leading zeros missing within number input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, ng-pattern

I need to have displayed, within the number input field, the leading zeros on integers between 00-09. I am using angularJS.

View/template for the input field(sorry for the style within the html):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_time">
  <h3 style="color:coral ;">{{field.displayName}}</h3>
  <div ng-controller="timeAdjustCtrl">
      <input style="float:left; width:auto; margin-right:5px;" type="number" min='0' max='23' placeholder="HH" ng-model="timeHH" ng-change="adjustTimeHhMm(timeHH, timeMM, field)" ng-init="initTimeValues(field)"  />
      <p style="float:left; line-height:50px;font-size:1em;">:</p>
      <input style="float:left;width:auto; margin-left:5px;" type="number" min='0' max='59' step="1" placeholder="MM" ng-model="timeMM" ng-change="adjustTimeHhMm(timeHH, timeMM, field)" ng-init="initTimeValues(field)" />
      <p style="float:left; line-height:50px;font-size:1em;"> {{field.theValues[0]}}</p>
  <br style="clear:both;" />
  </div>  
</script>
```

My controller:

```
  app.controller('timeAdjustCtrl', ['$scope', 
  function ($scope) {

    $scope.adjustTimeHhMm = function(hours, minutes, field) {
      console.log($scope.timeHH);
      var strHH = String(hours);
      var strMM = String(minutes);

      var path = "00";
      var newHH = path.substring(0, path.length - strHH.length) + strHH;
      var newMM = path.substring(0, path.length - strMM.length) + strMM;
      var newHhMm = String(newHH+':'+newMM);
      console.log(newHH + ':' + newMM);
      field.theValues[0] = newHhMm; 
      console.log($scope.timeHH);
    }

    $scope.initTimeValues = function(field){
      if (field.theValues[0] != 'undefined'){
        $scope.timeHH = parseInt(field.theValues[0].substring(0,2));
        $scope.timeMM = parseInt(field.theValues[0].substring(3,5));
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

This input field or set of two input fields set a time value(hours and minutes) which is stored as a single value(which remains in the desired format(HH:MM = ex=> 01:07)). The ng-model values($scope.timeHH & $scope.timeMM) dont hold the leading zeros within the input field.

[image]

I found an answer to this issue but I am not able to get it to work. This is the ([Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916185/angularjs-trims-leading-zeros-in-model-while-view-input-value-still-remains-unc)).

Here is the ode for the directive. It is not triggering on blur nor giving errors. Can anyone see structure or syntax issues?

View:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_time">
  <h3 style="color:coral ;">{{field.displayName}}</h3>
  <div ng-controller="timeAdjustCtrl">
      <input my-decimal style="float:left; width:auto; margin-right:5px;" type="number" min='0' max='23' placeholder="HH" ng-model="timeHH" ng-change="adjustTimeHhMm(timeHH, timeMM, field)" ng-init="initTimeValues(field)"  />
      <p style="float:left; line-height:50px;font-size:1em;">:</p>
      <input my-decimal style="float:left;width:auto; margin-left:5px;" type="number" min='0' max='59' step="1" placeholder="MM" ng-model="timeMM" ng-change="adjustTimeHhMm(timeHH, timeMM, field)" ng-init="initTimeValues(field)" />
      <p style="float:left; line-height:50px;font-size:1em;"> {{field.theValues[0]}}</p>
  <br style="clear:both;" />
  </div>  
</script>
```

Directive(catches on blur event on the input field and avoids leading zero trim)(placed under my controller for the input fields(not inside)):

```
 app.directive('myDecimals', function() {

    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

        elm.blur(function() {
            var val = ctrl.$viewValue;
            ctrl.$setViewValue(val * 1);
            ctrl.$render();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Input type=number removes leading zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437529/html5-input-type-number-removes-leading-zero)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not fond of this solution - there's an annoying flicker with this approach, and I'm especially not pleased with the setTimeout call - but it seems to work, and avoids the annoying "that's not a number" error Angular throws.

```
angular.module('application', [])
    .directive('zeroPadded', function(){
        return{
            // limit to classes and attributes only
            // to use with CSS class, include "zeroPadded" in the class attribute
            // to use with attributes, add "zero-padded" to the input tag
            restrict: 'AC',
            link : function(scope, element){
                function padZeroesElement(ele){
                    if(ele.value < 10){
                        ele.value = "0" + ele.value;
                    }
                };

                function padZeroes(event){
                    padZeroesElement(event.target);
                };

                element.on('change', padZeroes);

                // hacky but not sure how else to ensure it's zero-padded   from the start
                setTimeout(function(){
                    for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
                        padZeroesElement(element[i]);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        };
    });
```

And then your actual input looks something like this:

```
<input type="number" id="minute" ng-model="minute" min="0" max="59" step="1" zero-padded />
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm encountering a similar issue, where leading zero's are being trimmed from my "text" input. When I call `ngModel.$setViewValue("123.8900")` the text displayed in the input is "123.89" (the model is correctly set with zeros).

To solve this issue while still correctly setting the model, I call both:

```
var value = "123.8900";
ngModel.$setViewValue(value); //updates model but trims zeros in the view
inputEl[0].value = value; //prevents trimming of trailing zero but this alone wont update the model
```