# Hide 'Zero' value in input using typescript and Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
                   id="transactionAmount"
                   maxlength="10"
                   OnlyNumber="true" 
                   [(ngModel)]="userBalance.transactionAmount" 
                   name="transactionAmount"
                   placeholder="Amount"
                   required
                   #transactionAmount="ngModel">
```

1. Here I have to hide zero amount while user entering the values.
2. If he enters all zero's then only we have to hide not in cases like 20,30,100 etc...
3. I'm using Angular 2.

Comment: call a function on `change` event, where you patch null to that input if the value entered is all 0s

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Faisal tried patterns but it didn't work

Comment: @MohdTabishBaig I'm using change event and ill let you know if its worked or not

Comment: Maybe your answer is here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916185/angularjs-trims-leading-zeros-in-model-while-view-input-value-still-remains-unc

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
               id="transactionAmount"
               maxlength="10"
               OnlyNumber="true" 
               [(ngModel)]="userBalance.transactionAmount" 
               name="transactionAmount"
               placeholder="Amount"
               required
               #transactionAmount="ngModel"
               (keyup)="hideZero()>
```

> Added This **keyUp** event in Html and in **.ts** added below code

```
hideZero(){
if(this.userBalance.transactionAmount === '0' ){
    this.userBalance.transactionAmount = '';
}
```

}

*Working Absolutely fine*

Answer (score 0):

Try using (ngModelChange) event which will trigger when user types values. By using regex, you can remove the last zero value and update the DOM. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* In your ts */
validateNumber(value: String) {
 userBalance.transactionAmount = value && value.replace(/(?:0*)(\d*)/g, (_,value1) => {
 return value1;
})
}
```

```html
<input (input)="validateNumber($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 0 value don't display**

```
<span *ngIf="!pro.model === '0'">{{ pro.model }}</span>
```

Like this,
When model value is zero that time don't display model value.
If model value is not zero that time show model value in your html pages.