# Angularjs - display current date and save it on a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a view in angularjs and I'm just trying to display the current date.

**html**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lis.ModifiedDate" id="ModifiedDate">
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.ModifiedDate = $filter("ModifiedDate")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Can you please assist me here i want to display default date and the save it on a table.

Comment: do u need to display the filtered date in textbox ?

Comment: @K.Toress yes i want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the controller as,

```
 $scope.ModifiedDate = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

dont forget to inject `$filter` in to the controller

and html, you need to bind the value to textbox using `ModifiedDate` not with `lis.ModifiedDate`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ModifiedDate" id="ModifiedDate">
```

here is a sample [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KZXU8tcgKzla5Ckexpmv?p=preview)

Comment: Toress i 've problem when i'm saving date my c# code saves wrong date not the default date

Comment: are u sending `$scope.ModifiedDate` value to the backend ?

Comment: Toress yes im doing that

Answer (score 2):

Ok. What you're asking for is how to **format** the data from the ng-bind and also edit it. What you need to do is little known and called a formatter:

[How to do two-way filtering in angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js)

You need to define functions that both read and write the formatted date. That is actually easy, but Date() parses date formats pretty well. You cannot just use filter to do this though.

Alternatively, if you're happy with a long-date format in the field you CAN edit that, and it will be updated as a normal bound value. Pretty delicate though - see plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MPfGoNsG74rAV6UuvBKk?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Edit the date in the input:</p>
    <input ng-model="boundDate">
    {{boundDate | date : 'yyyy-mm-dd'}}
  </body>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.boundDate = new Date();
});
```

Comment: ok it does display now but nw i want to save it to a field so how to link the field with date i displayed

Comment: i want to display the  date in a textbox and the save then date to my table

Comment: thank you very much for responding. Toress got it right its working

Answer (score 2):

Use moment js it can convert date as required format

$scope.formattedDate = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

In html you use directly {{formattedDate}} it displays date in  yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: thank you very much for responding. Toress got it right its working