# AngularJS two-way binding expression with converter (similar to filter)

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that allows to bind some attributes in a two-way manner (`myDirective` can also set `someProp`):

```
<my-directive some-prop="myModel.someValue" />
```

Is there a way similar to filters that allows to transform the model value to a view value and back in the binding expression, like this:

```
<my-directive some-prop="myModel.someValue | myTwoWayConverter" />
```

What I've understood so far: usually, such forth and back conversion is done using `ngModel`s formatter and parser chain, but I have no ngModel in this case and would prefer a syntax that is similar  to the one used for filters.

Comment: Similar question has been aswered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27432203/2352017

Comment: @PabloDeNadai: similar, but not the same. More in the direction of my question goes the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js) that is linked there. But still it is not quite the answer, as it suggests to add a directive attribute (instead of a pipe-separated filter name) that hooks into ngModel's formatter/parser chain. It is limited to a directive using just one attribute the model could be bound to (ngModel).

Comment: The problem is that Angular doesn't really have a concept of a "two-way" filter. Filters are simply functions in a convenient namespace.

Answer (score -1):

You could have your directive use `ngModel`, then take advantage of the formatters pipeline. [Read here](http://www.chroder.com/2014/02/01/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/) for an example of a custom directive using `ngModel`. It's a lot of work for maybe not much pay-off. Maybe just use `$scope.$watch`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the point why this should answer my question. I'm well aware of `ngModel` and it's limitations.