# How to bind Array from angular $scope to the input

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array in $scope, say

```
$scope.my_array = ["val_1", "val_2", "val_3"]
```

To bind this array input element, I used ng-model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="my_array">
```

Now I want it to be display the array values as comma separated in input box, but nothing displays. Is this even possible?

In ng-repeat, it is iterating the values, so the array is available to the view.

**EDITED:** Thanks, the normal way is working for array binding. But in my case I was first using empty array:

```
$scope.my_array = []
```

Then, on ng-click function, I am grabbing the data-* attribute from the clicked element and pushing it to the array:

```
var item = $(".some-class").data("field-type");
$scope.my_array.push(item)
```

Iterating over this is working fine, but not working while setting to the input.

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/wr95vgom/.  Can you post some more of your code.

Comment: Yeah thanks, your jsfiddle code is also working for me. See the Edited info above.

Answer (score 0):

Look at another topic where two-way filtering is explained in details: [How to do two-way filtering in angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js)
in brief you should use ngModels' $parsers and $formatters collection to be able make .join(", ") before setting to input and to make .split(/, */) before setting value back to the model.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, I used

```
$scope.my_array = $scope.my_array.concat(item)
```

Instead of using .push() method.

I don't know if the `push` method of the array is a problem, but after concating the value into array, worked for me, now the array values are visible in input field.