# Changing the model value from the callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following input

```
<input id="mainOdd1Id" type="number" ng-model="data.mainOdd1" min="0" step="any" ng-attr-placeholder="{{data.mainOdd1}}" ng-focus="focus($event)"  ng-blur="blur($event)">
```

And the following function which execute on blur

```
$scope.blur = function($event){

  var id = $event.target.getAttribute('id');

  switch(id) {
    case "mainOdd1Id":
        $scope.data.mainOdd1 = func($scope.data.mainOdd1);
        break;
    case "mainOdd2Id":
        $scope.data.mainOdd2 = func($scope.data.mainOdd2);
        break;
    case "bkOdd1Id":
        $scope.data.bkOdd1 = func($scope.data.bkOdd1);
        break;
    case "bkOdd2Id":
        $scope.data.bkOdd2 = func($scope.data.bkOdd2);
        break;            
    default:
        break;
  } 
}
```

I would like to avoid the switch command by getting a "pointer" to the data field by the id and changing it. (*pointer = function(*pointer))

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a function that is supposed to be doing something? What is the "func" function? Some details on this will probably help with a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access properties by name using bracket notation.

Suppose you have a variable containing property name `propertyName`. Then you can access some object `obj` property like this `var propertyValue = obj[propertyName]`.

This should do the trick. If you remain the same naming convention that element's id is just `propName + 'Id'`

```
$scope.blur = function($event){
  // convert mainOdd1Id -> mainOdd1
  var id = $event.target.id.replace(/Id$/, '');

  if(id in $scope.data) { // check if prop is in scope.data
     $scope.data[id] = func($scope.data[id]); // perform update
  }
}
```

or you can pass correct property name from within template

```
<input id="mainOdd1Id" ... ng-focus="focus('mainOdd1')"  ng-blur="blur('mainOdd1')">


$scope.blur = function(propertyName){
  $scope.data[propertyName] = func($scope.data[propertyName]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'better' solution is to write a custom directive which attaches `func` to `ngModelController.$parsers` for the element where you use the directive.

```
module.directive('applyFunc', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(func);

            function func() { ... }
        }
    };
});
```

Then your html becomes:

```
<input id="mainOdd1Id" type="number" ng-model="data.mainOdd1"
     min="0" step="any"
     ng-attr-placeholder="{{data.mainOdd1}}" ng-focus="focus($event)"
     apply-func >
```

You can either write a separate directive for each parser or you could write a generic one that takes the function as from the attribute.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12947995/107660 for more on this and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController for the full documentation.

Comment: Thanks, does apply-func translate to the directive name? applyFunc?

Comment: Yes, give your directive in a name in camel case and convert that to any of the Angular naming conventions for attributes the simplest of which is to lowercase and hyphen separate the words.

Comment: Hey, I tried this method, and I see the function is only being called on a valid input from the user. What can I use so it will be called on blur?

Comment: I think I got it, I bound between the blur element and a function in the controller. Thanks